# When I use my computer name to make connection for oracle it shows error

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g

When I use my computer name to make connection for oracle it shows error, I know that I could use the term `localhost` instead but I want to use my computer name, what should I do?

Code:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.
                        getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@**Fozhan_PC**:1521:SHARIF",
                        "amirsam", "myjava123");
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" 
              java.sql.SQLException: 
              Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle should be able to resolve your computer name to your IP. So either add a DNS record for your computer, or if oracle is local than add entry into your /etc/hosts. Of course here I am assuming that you are using a linux machine. If you are on windows add that record to c:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file.

Comment: I am using windows 8, could you please explain what should I exactly do in this address, c:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts, thanks

Comment: Open that file as admin and add a record as the following (of course change the ip and machine name)
    
      192.168.122.133       mymachine mymachine.madomain.com

Answer (score 0):

It can be either of two reasons:

1. DNS service is not able to resolve Name to IP for
2. If resolved correctly, then either ip/port is not accessible.

There are multiple ways of checking DNS to IP, but you can try following (more java way)

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("Fozhan_PC");
System.out.println(addr.getHostAddress());
```

or there are many other utilities like nslookup/dig/resolve etc.

> If you do not want to depend on DNS service for resolution then I'll suggest to either use IP/add a static entry to /etc/hosts

---

Connectivity can be tested via

```
ping <IP>
telnet <IP> <PORT>
nc -z <IP> <PORT>
```

> If connectivity turns out to be a problem then check your network setup and firewall settings and allow tcp connections on DB server for `1521` port or simple disable/stop firewall.

Hope this helps you in resolving this issue :).